# How can I replace an object in mongodb without specifying a filter using the C# driver?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using the C# driver 2.0. I have a POCO that I am storing in mongo that looks like this:

```
public class TestObject
{
     [BsonId]
     public Guid Id { get; set; }
     public string Property1 { get; set; }
}
```

I am storing the object using a generic method like this:

```
public async void Insert<T>(T item)
{
        var collection = GetCollection<T>();

        await collection.InsertOneAsync(item);
}
```

I would like to have a similar method to Update an object. However, the `ReplaceOneAsync` method requires a filter be specified.

I would like to simply update the same object, based on whatever the `[BsonId]` property is. Any one know if this is possible?

Comment: You need a filter with the id. Otherwise you will update all the documents.

Comment: But since I am trying to create a generic method to do the update for me, i don't know which field is the ID field on the object.

Comment: you can add an interface that only has an ID and accept that. Or use reflection to see what has BsonId. But you need an Id for the filter

Answer (score 7):

I completely agree with @i3arnon, typical solution is next:

interface for your models:

```
public interface IEntity
{
    string Id { get; set; }
}
```

save method in your base repository

```
public async Task SaveAsyn<T>(T entity) where T : IEntity
{
    var collection = GetCollection<T>();
    if (entity.Id == null)
    {
        await collection.InsertOneAsync(entity);
    }
    else
    {
        await collection.ReplaceOneAsync(x => x.Id == entity.Id, entity);
    }
}
```

And also about ID, you can continue using ID as Guid, but more robust and simpler solution is using string ([explanation about Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11355792/with-mongodb-and-guids-for-the-id-of-documents-what-is-efficient-way-to-store-th)).